# how to determine the iscsi target's naa in linux

Tags: linux, storage, storage-area-network, iscsi

I understand that iSCSI uses iqn / eui to identify target LUN. Once I have discovered the iSCSI target and logged in is there a way to determine the LUN's NAA id for the remote target from a linux (RHEL/Centos) machine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `scsi_id` to send the INQUIRY command to the device to get its identifiers.

The following example is based on the old `scsi_id` syntax that is used in RHEL 5.

```
/sbin/scsi_id -g -p 0x83 -s /block/sdd  
36006016018202a00520d0d1ea99de111
```

In the new syntax as in RHEL/CentOS 6 the long option format is used.

```
scsi_id --whitelisted --page=0x83 --device=/dev/sdd
```

Here the first digit indicates a NAA identifier (`3`), the second digit indicates the IEEE Registered extended format (`6`), next `00:60:16` is the 24-bit vendor ID. In this example we have a vendor ID that maps to EMC Corporation's CLARIION OUI. The next 9 digits are the vendor specific id: `018202a00`. The remaining 16 digits are the specific naa ID `520d 0d1e a99d e111`.

This would correspond to 128-bit NAA identifier `naa.6006016018202a00520d0d1ea99de111`

The `-g` or `--whitelisted` option is needed since by default scsi_id blacklists all devices.